# Intersection of nested compact sets in a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Suppose that a non-empty Hausdorff space $X$ is compact and there is a continuous map $f:X \to X$. Let $X_1=X$ and put $X_{n+1} = f(X_n)$ inductively for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> Prove that $A = \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ is non-empty.

Thoughts: Since $f$ is continuous, we have that $X_{n}$ is compact for all $n$. Furthermore, they are all closed because of $X$'s Hausdorffness.

In a normal metric space this would be easier, using the equivalence of compactness and sequential compactness, by constructing a sequence such that $a_n \in X_n$, and using the fact that it necessarily has a convergent subsequence with limit in the intersection.

Any hints would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. Let $U_n := X \setminus X_n$. If we have $\bigcap_n X_n = \emptyset$, we would have $\bigcup_n U_n = X$ with open $U_n$. Now use compactness.

Comment: So $\mathcal{U} = \{U_i\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an open cover of $X$, by compactness we can extract a finite cover $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of $X$, but then what?

Comment: Then $X = \bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i = U_n$ (the $U_n$ are increasing). But $U_n = X$ gives $X_n = \emptyset$, which is wrong. (If $x \in X$, then $f^{n-1}(x) \in X_n$.